# Using BasicHttpBinding but exception: 'CustomBinding ... lacks a TransportBindingElement'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service that I do not have control over.
I am receiving a `The CustomBinding on the ServiceEndpoint ... lacks a TransportBindingElement` exception but my service is using `BasicHttpBinding` which I believe should have a `TransportBindingElement` already and obviously it is not a CustomBinding so I believe the exception is misleading.

The WCF service to being consumed from a .Net 8 Class libabary, I was previously using .Net 7 and it was working fine but now after updating to .Net 8 and now I try it, I get this exception.

The `csproj` for the Class Libaray is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.10.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Gateways\Gateways.vbproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

[image]

Is there anyone with exp in .Net 8 and WCF who could help me?

Comment: The first problem is **BasicHttpbinding**, which belongs to **System.ServiceModel.HTTP**. It's generally meant to help **.NET Core** call WCF services. Your version is **4.10**. You can try updating to the latest version:[System.ServiceModel.Http 8.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http/)

Comment: But the reason can also be. **.NET 8** itself exists.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem could also be. .NET 8 itself. This document I think is helpful to you:[Breaking changes in .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/8.0?toc=%2Fdotnet%2Ffundamentals%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fdotnet%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json)

Comment: Thank you I will update my packages and try again when I get the chance

Comment: If you still have any questions, you can continue to leave a comment.